# Calling a jQuery plugin and not specifying a selcetor

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a small plugin to change the primary and secondary color on a page.

Now it's working when you specify a selector but i'm trying to workaround this

my code:

```
(function($) {

$.fn.Color = function( options ) {

    // Establish our default settings
     var settings = $.extend({
        primary_color           : null,
        secondary_color         : null
    }, options);

    return this.each( function() {

        if ( settings.primary_color ) {

            $(".primary_color").css( 'color', settings.primary_color);
            $(".bg-primary_color").css( 'color', settings.primary_color);
        }

        if ( settings.secondary_color  ) {
            $(".secondary_color").css( 'color', settings. secondary_color);
        }
    });

};

}(jQuery));
```

and in the page i'm adding this:

```
$('h1').Color({
  primary_color  : '#000',
  secondary_color : '#fff' 
});
```

Comment: You have to specify your issue.  what's the problem here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery was really designed to work on elements. The smartest thing to do would be to pass in a selector, and design your plugin to restrict itself to that selector's scope:

```
(function($) {

$.fn.Color = function( options ) {

    // Establish our default settings
     var settings = $.extend({
        primary_color           : null,
        secondary_color         : null
    }, options);

    return this.each( function() {

        if ( settings.primary_color ) {

            $(".primary_color", this).css( 'color', settings.primary_color);
            $(".bg-primary_color", this).css( 'color', settings.primary_color);
        }

        if ( settings.secondary_color  ) {
            $(".secondary_color", this).css( 'color', settings. secondary_color);
        }
    });

};

}(jQuery));
```

Then, choose an appropriate selector when you're calling it. If you really want everything on the page to have this style applied, use `body`:

```
$('body').Color({
  primary_color  : '#000',
  secondary_color : '#fff' 
});
```

The advantage to this approach is that if requirements change in the future, you can narrow down the scope of your behavior to other elements.

---

If you don't want to scope these effects to a specific element, then perhaps a jQuery plugin isn't the right approach. Why not just declare a `Color` function directly? It would be a lot simpler.

```
Color({
  primary_color  : '#000',
  secondary_color : '#fff' 
});
```

---

As a final note, I should point out that this specific use case (changing colors based on class selectors) is best left to CSS, not JavaScript. The simplest thing to do is just to use CSS styles:

```
.primary_color { color: #000 }
.secondary_color { color: #fff }
```

So unless there's a specific reason that you need to dynamically change these colors, I'd avoid making a plugin for this entirely.